# Require a JSON file in Node.js Then Access/Iterate Through It?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, iteration

I believe the error here lies in how I have my Json structured, but this is what is happening.

I have a Json file that looks something like this (omitting key values to protect information):

```
{
    "services" : [
        {

            "server" : "info",
            "baseURL" : "http://info.info.net",
            "controlPanelURL" : "http://infoadmin.info.net",
            "paths" : {
                "restaurantManagerPath" : "/info",
                "transactionManagerPath" : "/info",
                "userManagerPath" : "/info",
                "recordHistoryPath" : "/info"
            }
        },

        {
            "server" : "info",
            "baseURL" : "http://info.info.net",
            "controlPanelURL" : "http://infoadmin.info.net",
            "paths" : {
                "restaurantManagerPath" : "/info",
                "transactionManagerPath" : "/info",
                "userManagerPath" : "/info",
                "recordHistoryPath" : "/info"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

I require this file in my main app.js entry-point like so:

```
const Data = require("./data.json");
```

Now, if I `console.log(Data)`, I will be shown this:
[image]

Now for my problem. It seems I cannot "access" this as an object even though I know using require() on a Json file automatically parses it. Nor can I loop through it with a for...in loop. Here are some examples. Please ignore the "this.json" file, it is a copy of the actual "data.json" file.

[image]

[image]

Any info would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance for you input on my probably dumb question.

Comment: `data.services.forEach(e => console.log(e));` or `for (let service of data.services) {console.log(service)};` as data.services is an array

Comment: That appears to have worked... My concern is that my "IntelliSense" had the Data and services objects "greyed-out, appearing to be incorrect selections.. Also can you explain me the difference in using (let service of Data.services) rather than using (let service IN Data.services)?

Comment: If you want IntelliSense for things like this you need to use TypeScript I believe.